# Is it true that RDF lacks precisely described meaning?

Tags: rdf

I have a question regarding issues in RDF for representing Semantic Web. The speaker at the tutorial http://videolectures.net/training06_sure_stsw/ says that RDF would lack precisely described meaning.

I don't get it. It's been mentioned that RDF describes data like lets says, I have a triplet

```
<http://www.mydomain.com#me> <http://dublincore.com/#title> "Myname"
```

Here I can dereference the URIs and get more information about me and the title attribute from Dublin Core. So we have described it, isn't it? Any insights will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that it lacks precisely described meaning is misleading.  By itself, it does not impart a lot of meaning beyond what it specified by the standard RDF model theory.  But it is very amenable to use with either RDF schemas (RDFS) or OWL2, both of which allow you to give varying levels of meaning to the data you are representing in RDF.